# each time i run my program after answering the first Question ==> strange page apears to me (Like a new strange kind of error )

Tags: c

After the program asks me to choose one of the four options I choose (1) then it moves to the first Question and asks me to Enter a name BUT after I type anything the program stops and take me to another (Like tab in Visual studio) + the RUN page also freezes and I can't even close it = so the only way for me is to close the file and open it again. PLEASE HELP.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        int choose, dosage, quantity;
        char code[10];
        char name[32];
        char produce[64];
        float population;
        {
            printf("COVID-19 Vaccination System \n");
            printf("1:- Inventory Creation \n");
            printf("2:- Update Vaccine Quantities \n");
            printf("3:- Search Vaccine \n");
            printf("4:- Produce a list of all Vaccines and their distributed Quantities \n");
            printf("5:- EXIT \n\n");
            printf("==>");
            scanf_s("\n%d", &choose);
            if (choose == 1)
            {
                char ch;
                FILE* cv;
                errno_t err;
                cv = fopen_s(&cv, "vaccine.txt", "w");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Full information %d \n", i + 1);
                    printf(" Name of Vaccine : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%s", name, 15);
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Code %c \n", i + 1);
                    printf(" Vaccine Code : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%s", code, 4);
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Producing Country %c \n", i + 1);
                    printf("Producing Country : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%s", produce, 15);
                    printf("Please Enter Dosage Required %d \n", i + 1);
                    printf("Dosage Required (MAX=2 - MIN=1) : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%d", dos[enter image description here][1]age, 2);
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Quantity %d \n", i + 1);
                    scanf_s("\n%d", quantity, 15);
    
                    fprintf(cv, "%s %s %s %d %f %d", name, code, produce, dosage, population, quantity);
                    fclose(cv);
                }
            }
```

[an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqpHE.png)

Comment: Please show what data you are entering, note thjat `%s` format stops at the first space. Aside, please remove the `\n` newline from every `scanf_s` format string.

Comment: I can see in your image that you are ignoring compiler warnings - don't, unless you understand them fully. `scanf_s("\n%d", dos[enter image description here][1]age, 2);` - I'll assume that's a typo for `scanf_s("\n%d", dosage, 2);`, but your compiler should be telling you that `dosage` should be a pointer, and that the `2` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `fopen_s` incorrectly with

```
cv = fopen_s(&cv, "vaccine.txt", "w");
```

Unlike `fopen` it does not *return* the file pointer, but a status. I suggest

```
errno_t res = fopen_s(&cv, "vaccine.txt", "w");
if (res != 0) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

You should always check whether a file has opened successfully.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111893/each-time-i-run-my-program-after-answering-the-first-question-strange-page-a/68112000#comment120383351_68111893), the `%d` specifier needs an *address* (and no size) so

```
scanf_s("\n%d", quantity, 15);
```

should be

```
scanf_s("%d", &quantity);
```

and others too. MS does warn about errors such as these, don't ignore them!